# What happens when we do the re-declaration of object in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Can anyone please explain me why foo.bar is undefined?
As per my understanding,it should have printed 3. Please correct me if i am wrong.

Here is the code.

```
    var bar = 1,
    foo = {};

    foo: {
        bar: 2;
        baz: ++bar;
    };

    foo.bar; //undefined
    foo.baz; //undefined

    bar; //2
```

Thanks in Advance;

Comment: Instead of `foo: {}` type `foo = {}`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have typo is `foo = {` not `foo: {`. Also properties must seperate with commas `,` not semicolon:

```js
var bar = 1,
    foo = {};

foo = {
  bar: 2,
  baz: ++bar
};

console.log(foo.bar); //2
console.log(foo.baz); //2
console.log(bar); //2
```

Also please take a look [Object initializer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer)

Comment: why ++bar is not incrementing to 3??

Comment: Because `1 + 1 = 2`. The variable `bar` has nothing to do with `foo.bar`

Comment: Because you have initialized  `var bar = 1` so `++bar` giving you `1+1=2`. Whereas `bar` and `foo.bar` is different.

Comment: `bar` is a global variable and is value is 1. The other `bar` is property of the obejct `foo`. You increase global variable `bar` by 1.

Comment: Oops..Got it. Thanks all

Answer (score 4):

You are not redeclaring `foo`. You are using a [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label).

You should have

```
foo = {
    bar: 2,
    baz: ++bar
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Because your syntax is wrong. It should be `=` assignment operator when reinitialize variable of `javascript`:

```
var bar = 1,
foo = {};

foo = {
    bar: 2,
    baz: ++bar,
};

foo.bar; //2
foo.baz; //2

bar; //2
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/2md1ynr1/)